# Error al implementar socket io en angular 10

Tags: angular, socket, socket.io, websocket, angular10

Tengo un problema al usar socket io en angular versión 10, cuando implemento el código en una versión completamente nueva funciona bien pero necesito implementarlo en una versión de código ya construida, el error es el siguiente...

[image: Error arrojado en consola]

Estoy utilizando la siguiente documentación de implementación de **npm install ngx-socket-io**

Esta es la versión

```
"ngx-socket-io": "^3.2.0",
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenida señorita, le sugiero revisar estas recomendaciones para que su pregunta tenga mayor chance de ser respondida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Puedes agregar, tu código, como lo implementas, las versiones de el socketio que estas usando y de angular.

Comment: Gracias! Lo edito!